# Convert Pandas DataFrame Columns to Object Data Type esp DateTime[64] after converting from UTC to EST timezone

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

**Problem:**

I have a data Frame extracting the data from Snowflake which has around 120 columns out of which few are date columns in UTC format. 
Original data Frame:

data

```
a   b   c   d

1   ad  1.0 2020-01-20 12:21:20
```

using below code I have changed to EST format.

df.d=df.d.dt.tz_convert['EST']  ---> Working fine.

Data after timezone conversion:
data:

```
a   b   c   d
1   ad  1.0 2020-01-20 07:21:20-05:00
```

Name : d, dtype:datetime64[ns,US/Eastern]

Now I m trying to convert the dataframe dtypes to Obj using below:

data_new=pd.Dataframe.from_records(data).convert_dtypes().astype(str)

OutPut of the above code:

data:

```
a   b   c   d
1   ad  1.0 2020-01-20 12:21:20
```

Name : d, dtype:datetime64[ns,US/Eastern]

**Please help me what am I doing wrong here. why the converted DF is not having the exact value of column d [its converting back to UTC format while applying asdype.**

Comment: did you try it with dt.strftime including a %z ?

Comment: Yes after trying it was solved. Thnx